# Fastest way to query collection for ALL documents

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongoose

My collection has approximately 500 documents, which will be double that in a few weeks:

How can I make getting all the documents faster?  I'm currently using db.registrations.find(), so that I can have all the documents available for searching, sorting, and filtering data.  Using skip/limit makes the query display quickly, but you can't search all the registrations for players, and that's necessary.

My schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var playerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  first: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  last: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  phone: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  address: {
    address: String,
    city: String,
    state: String,
    zip: String,
    country: {
      type: String,
      "default" : "USA"
    },
    adult: Boolean
  }

});

var registrationsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  event : {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  day : {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  group : {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  field : {
    type: String,
  },
  price : {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  players : [playerSchema],
  net : Number,
  team : {
    type: Number,
    min: 0,
    max: 7,
    "default" : null
  },
  notes: String,
  paymentID : {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    "default": "VOLUNTEER"
  },
  paymentStatus : {
    type: String,
    "default" : "PAID"
  },
  paymentNote : String,
  // users : [userSchema],
  active : {
   type: Boolean,
   default: true
  },
  users: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }],
  createdOn : {
    type : Date,
    "default" : Date.now
  },
  updatedLast : {
    type: Date
  }
});

mongoose.model('Registration', registrationsSchema);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no big deal to load 1000 records from mongodb using mongoose. I did it in the past (2-3k records) and it worked well as long as I respected this 2 rules:

### Don't load all the mongoose stuff

Use [lean](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) query.
This way it won't load all the mongoose methods / attributes and it will get just the data of your objects. You can't use `.save()` or other methods but **it's way faster to load**.

### Use stream to load your data.

Streams are a good way to load large dataset with nodejs/mongoose. It will read the data block by block from mongodb and send them to your application for usage. You will avoid the tipical case :

> - I wait 2 seconds my data and my server is idle
> - My server is 100% CPU during 2 seconds to process the data I got and the db is idle.
>
> With streams, in this example your total time will be ~2s instead of 2+2=4s

To load data from stream with mongoose use the [.cursor()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-cursor) function to change your request to a [nodejs stream](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.8.21/api/stream.html#stream_readable_stream).

**Here is an example to load all your players fast**

```
const allPlayers = [];

const cursor = Player.find({}).lean().cursor();
cursor.on('data', function(player) { allPlayers.push(player); });
cursor.on('end', function() { console.log('All players are loaded here'); });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve your objective using the following ways.

1. By default if you query for mongoose document, it will load with all of it's attributes and other necessary meta-data required(ie.,with lean = false). so if you use lean() function, it will load only a plain java script objects and it won't return even setter and corresponding getter methods. So that you can get all the documents very very fast. And you will get High performance. that's what the magic of lean() function on the back ground.
2. Another suggestion is as a thumb rule, please maintain proper indexing as per your requirement for each collection to get good performance while querying.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: I did add indexing, and will try the lean function.  I didn't know about that one!  Thanks.